# Guide in understanding OPC concepts

Tags: c#, .net, opc

im trying to learn OPC for a project we are developing,

i thought i understood a couple of things but a discussion with a colleague showed me otherwise

So, please correct me if wrong on these terms/concepts:

- OPC is basically a protocol that allows devices to talk using the
  same language, in the same way we have http, tcp and all others.
- When i say OPC Server, i mean a computer/program connected to a
  specified device, with the proper driver that exposes access to said
  device via the OPC protocol;
- When i say OPC Client, i mean a device/software that can connect to
  that server or to the original device (aka the one that produces the
  data) to read and and write some data
- OPC UA allows me to connect to legacy devices that are using the old
  opc (the dcom/com version) and future devices
- OPC allows for auto-configuration of devices, meaning i can get a
  list of what info the device provides, and configure them according
  to what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, you seem to have stated things correctly.

The last bit about "auto-configuration" seems a bit optimistic, unless I'm taking you too literally.  There's nothing automated about it.  You can retrieve lists of servers, nodes, topics, etc.  But those are only for convenience.

Have you found the [OPC Foundation website](https://www.opcfoundation.org/)?  A wealth of information and they provide the libraries.

Comment: i have come to associate .org domains to non-profit organizations...not anymore

Comment: its not auto-configuration really, its just that we are using that term to differentiaten the kind of configuration we are trying to implement with the one we currently have. basically we have our columns, we query the device for what columns/data-types (im guessing there is a proper name to that) it provides and we can mix and match them on the fly, as opposed to nearly having to code the driver itself, which is what we have been doing so far

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow the configuration issues.  OPC has a fundamental equivalency to DDE in that you request a data item (Server/Topic/Item [in DDE] == Node/Service/Tag [in OPC]) and that returns a value.  In our software, we provide a UI in which the user creates "links" and these links define the requests we make to the OPC/DDE server.  There're really not much to configure unless you are creating a management interface.  I guess that's an entirely different ball of wax.